# Intuit Quickbooks OAuth version 1.0 or 2.0?

Tags: django, oauth, oauth-2.0, intuit-partner-platform

I am using Django for my website/app and I want to integrate quickbooks. I wasn't sure whether you are using Oauth version 1.0 or 2.0. Also the documentation is more specific for PHP but the django-oauth-toolkit documentation I THINK is more geared towards hosting your own Oauth than connecting as a client. So although my main question is what version are you using any links to where I could read up on connecting with django would be greatly appreciated. I do have PHP still setup but I have been converting all my modules to django (python) and I was trying to avoid that. I thought reading the IETF protocol might help my understanding but there is the older version [1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) by the original author and then the newer [2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) that is currently supported. He does seem to have a pretty good [beginner's guide](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/) but at the same time he seems a little ['disgruntled'](http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/26/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/), if that's the right word, about the newer version. Also I believe the django-oauth-toolkit is version 2.0 protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OAuth v1.0.

They have a bit of documentation here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/0085_develop_quickbooks_apps/0004_authentication_and_authorization

I would highly recommend you find an existing OAuth library for Django/Python - writing your own is likely going to be a painful process.

Comment: Yeah that's where I started. I found the django-oauth-toolkit but I think that uses oauth 2.0 I'm not sure if it's reverse compatible or not.

Comment: @TomasoAlbinoni Link fixed. It's easily findable with a Google search as well.